# wp_redirect doen't work

Tags: plugins, wp-redirect

I am writing a simple plugin to accept a user number, show a form with information about the user, then post a payment amount. The user number is obtained from this http file include_once(PLCOA_ADMIN_PATH . 'views/plcoa-payment-start.php'); and loads perfectly. The info form is filled out using the php file include_once(PLCOA_ADMIN_PATH . 'views/plcoa-payment-add.php');
It has only one field - the payment amount in the form. When the Submit Button is pressed it runs this function.

```
function payment_post(){
if ($_POST['post_action'] == 'Post')
{
    //I do my db INSERT here
}
wp_redirect (PLCOA_ADMIN_PATH . 'views/plcoa-payment-start.php');
exit;
```

}

I've spent hours trying to figure out what I have wrong and I know it's simple. This is all running in the admin area. If I re_direct to an external site it works just fine. Is there some other way to re-direct, after inserting the record in the db, back to the start form?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think you understand [`wp_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) incorrectly.

This function redirects you to a different URL. It’s like sending `header('Location: ...');`

On the other hand, it looks like you’re trying to pass local path as its param. So it won’t work - such path is not a valid URL address.

Comment: Many thanks. I did misunderstand. I should have picked up on that when I went to an external site. What is the best way to back to my beginning page? The page I want to get to is on my admin_menu.

Answer (score 0):

Please pay attention to @KrzysiekDróżdż answer.

```
wp_redirect (PLCOA_ADMIN_PATH . 'views/plcoa-payment-start.php');
```

should be either something like

```
wp_redirect (PLCOA_ADMIN_URL . 'views/plcoa-payment-start.php'); 
// Assuming PLCOA_ADMIN_URL is defined
```

OR

```
include_once (PLCOA_ADMIN_PATH . 'views/plcoa-payment-start.php'); // Recommended
```

Comment: Your second suggestion worked - except that I dropped out of the admin wrapped area. All I have is a white screen with the form that I want. From there if I enter a user number I do get back in the admin wrapper with the correct form.

Comment: I guessed from your question that your code uses `include_once()` for different tasks on main admin page.  I hope you will now adjust your code using some `if... else` decisions to fit your needs.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll haven't used include_once() before so I'll look into it.

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking. I have used include_once. My problem now is that my form looks like it was created using straight php code. All of the wp admin header and side bars are gone. Could that we cause by the content of my html? It does work from the admin_menu.

Comment: Based on last line of your comment on @Krzysiek Dróżdż answer, it is suggested that you should use   `wp_redirect (  menu_page_url( 'your_menu_slug')  );`   where `your_menu_slug` should be replaced with the slug with which your admin page is registered.